# Of the same tags, I want to extract only the tags I want

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am studying crawling Using Python3.

[image]

```
<ul class='report_thum_list img'>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
```

In this, I just want to pull out the li tag.

So, I wrote that

```
ulTag = soup.findAll('ul', class_='report_thum_list img')
liTag = ulTag[0].findAll('li')
# print(len(liTag))
```

I expected twenty (there are 20 posts per page.)

But over 100 came out.

Because There is another li tag in the li tag.

[image]

I do not want to extract the li tag inside the div tag.

How can I pull out 20 li tags?

This is my code.

```
url = 'https://www.posri.re.kr/ko/board/thumbnail/list/63?page='+ str(page)
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')

ulTag = soup.find('ul', class_='report_thum_list img')
# liTag = ulTag.findAll('li')
liTag = ulTag.findChildren('li')
print(len(liTag))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 liTag = soup.select('ul.report_thum_list > li')
```

Use CSS selector, it's very easy to use

Comment: @ Sorry. I wrote the findChildren('li') but it doesn't  work it.
Result is 160. Also, liTag=ulTag.findAll('li')'s result is 160, too